# Selenium not clearing website search bar with .clear()

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm scraping a website where the searchbar auto-fills with the last thing I search. If I use `.clear()`, the search bar still continues to append the last-searched item.

```
for sku in skus_to_find:
    search_bar = WebDriverWait(driver,100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@accesskey, 'S')]")))
    search_bar.clear()
    search_bar.send_keys(sku)
    search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

How can I better clear out the search bar on a web page prior to `.send_keys()`?

Answer (score 1):

added logic to click on cross, so it cleans the text box before you add new sku.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

#PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
baseurl = "http://www.zoro.com"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(baseurl)

def use_driver_current_html(driver):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    return soup

file = open('zoro_skus.txt')

skus_to_find = []
product_list = []

for line in file:
    line = line.replace('\n', '')
    skus_to_find.append(line)

for sku in skus_to_find:
    search_bar = WebDriverWait(driver,100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@accesskey, 'S')]")))
    time.sleep(2)
    search_bar.send_keys(sku)
    search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    #below try and catch added
    try:
        cross_click=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//*[@class='svg-icon zcl-icon zcl-icon--small'])[2]")))
        cross_click.click()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
```